# BIGINT shifting in MySQL

Tags: mysql, bigint

Hey all, I think this might be a bug, but it's killing me.  I am using MySQL 5.1.41 on an Ubuntu Linux server.  I'm trying to write a function to create a random signed BIGINT value.  Because the precision of RAND() is too small to generate the full range of possible BIGINT values, I decided to try to combine four 32-bit words using bit operators.

I fired up MySQL Workbench, and tried the following to see if bit shift operators work correctly with negative numbers:

```
SELECT HEX((0x1ACE - 0x8000) << 0x10);
```

0x1ACE - 0x8000 is -25906, so if I shift 16 bits to the left, I should be multiplying by 65536, right?  The answer I got back was 0xFFFFFFFF9ACE0000, which is the signed representation of -1697775616, or -25906 * 65536.  Wunderbar, it works!!!

So my plan was to use that to generate the first 32-bit word of the random signed BIGINT, and use a simple loop to add three more 32-bit words to the value, shifting the bits over four bytes at a time.  Excitedly, I started out by putting the following code in my function, using a hard-coded value to test my plan with:

```
DECLARE x BIGINT;
SET x = (0x1ACE - 0x8000) << 0x10;
```

If I set the value so that the value being shifted is positive, everything works fine.  However, after performing this calculation with a shifted negative value (-25906 in this case), I kept getting that x was 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, which is the maximum positive value of a signed 64-bit integer.  I'm totally baffled.  The *exact same operation* is generating a totally different result depending on whether it is in a SET operation in a function or a SELECT statement.

So I started messing around with whether x was signed or unsigned and things got really weird.  I tried making x unsigned and tried the following:

```
DECLARE x BIGINT UNSIGNED;
SET x = (0x1ACE - 0x8000);
```

When I did that, I got x equal to zero.  Not surprising, since x is unsigned and the result is negative.  However, on a lark, I tried this:

```
DECLARE x BIGINT UNSIGNED;
SET x = (0x1ACE - 0x8000) << 0;
```

To my surprise, x was set to 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF9ACE!

Can someone please help?  I've been working for hours on a function that does nothing more than efficiently generates a random signed BIGINT, I'm tired, and the more I look at this stuff, the more frustrated I get and the less sense I can make of it.  Any help, either in explaining what's going on here or advice in writing this function so that it consistently works now and, if this is a bug, in later version if it gets fixed, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think the problem here may be that MySql can use different data format for internal operations (substraction and shifting), try to write operations step by step: You can change SET x = (0x1ACE - 0x8000) << 0x10; to SET x=0x1ACE; SET x=x-0x8000; SET x=x<<0x10; or something like it. Or try "SELECT (0x1ACE - 0x8000) << 0x10 INTO  x;" syntax http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into-statement.html .

Comment: No dice.  When I split it up into line-by-line operations, everything is correct until I SET x = x << 0x10;  It still gives me 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.  If I SELECT x << 0x10 INTO x; it gives me the same result.  This is so frustrating!

Comment: Okay, now I'm just getting pissed off.  I just tried doing a SET guid = 0x1ABC - 0x8000 and got 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF9ABC.  So far, so good.  Then if I do a SET guid = guid << 0, I get 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.  This is clearly wrong, and there's something not kosher going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I think I just figured it out.  According to [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html#operator_left-shift), the bit shift operators result in **unsigned** 64-bit integers.  So when you try:

```
DECLARE guid BIGINT;   -- signed BIGINT
SET guid = -25924;     -- = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF9ABC
SET guid = guid << 0;  -- Result: 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

What is happening is that in order for guid << 0 to return an **unsigned** integer, it is trying to convert guid from a negative signed integer to an unsigned integer, resulting in 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, then shifting it over zero places, which is an identity operation resulting in the same 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

It appears that multiplication (*), however, works correctly on signed and unsigned numbers.  I can achieve my desired result by the following:

```
DECLARE guid BIGINT;        -- signed BIGINT
SET guid = -25924;          -- = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF9ABC
SET guid = guid * 0x10000;  -- = Result: 0xFFFFFFFF9ABC0000 Woot! \o/
```

Comment: Thank you for posting solution, I thought about it, but then I don't understand why SELECT HEX((0x1ACE - 0x8000) << 0x10); works.